# Sqlite <table constraint> expected

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I wrote `sqlite` sentence in this form :

```
String SQL_CREATE_BACKUP  ="CREATE TABLE " +smsEntry.BACKUP +"("
            +smsEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            +smsEntry.BACKUP_LAST_MODE +" INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            +smsEntry.BACKUP_CURRENT_MODE +" INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            +smsEntry.BACKUP_LAST_TYPE +" INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            +smsEntry.BACKUP_CURRENT_TYPE +" INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            +smsEntry.BACKUP_MILLI_DATE +" LONG NOT NULL,"
            +smsEntry.BACKUP_CURRENT_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

 db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_BACKUP);
```

But when I want to run this code, I receive this error message:

```
<column definition name> or <table constraint>expected,got 'current_date'
```

How can i fix this bug?

Thankes.

Comment: Can you show what the value of SQL_CREATE_BACKUP after building the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLite don't allow you to name columns with reserved names.

[Here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) you can find the complete list

> How can i fix this bug?

change the column name 'current_date' into something else

> How to use a keywoard as a name?

If you want to use a keyword as a name, you need to quote it. There are four ways of quoting keywords in SQLite:

- 'keyword'     A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
- "keyword"     A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.
- [keyword]     A keyword enclosed in square brackets is an identifier. This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MS Access and SQL Server and is included in SQLite for compatibility.
- `keyword`     A keyword enclosed in grave accents (ASCII code 96) is an identifier. This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MySQL and is included in SQLite for compatibility.

Comment: *SQLite don't allow you to name columns with reserved names* not totally true as you can enclose the column name e.g. `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable ("current_date" TEXT);` will work. [SQL As Understood By SQLite - SQLite Keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). Not that I advise/condone such usage.

Comment: @MikeT Mentioned that too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think 'current_date' is a SQL keyword. Just change it to any other name, like 'present_date' and you will be good to go.